# jQuery selectors don't work correctly within web.py

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
<head>
    <script src="/static/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = jQuery('#continue').attr('value');
        alert(value);
    </script>
    <title>$pageTitle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="notifier">
        <form>
            <button>Cancel</button>
            <button id="continue" value="next">Continue</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I wish I had `next`, but instead I get `undefined` message in alert. It happens even if i try to get `html()` from any other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#continue` element doesn't ready when you are trying to get it's attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value = $('#continue').attr('value');
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in a document.ready handler so that has access to the jQuery object, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var value = jQuery('#continue').attr('value');
        alert(value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Or put `<script>` in the end of the `<body>`, which is considered to be a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

In the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) it says:

> **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method returns *undefined* for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, `.attr()` should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the `.prop()` method.

From your code example i see you're using jQuery 1.7.1, so probably using the `.prop()` method instead of `.attr()` will solve your problem.